# How to generate UTF8 CSV file in php with well rendered quotes?

Tags: php, symfony, csv, utf-8

I want to create a CSV file in php, encoded in UTF-8, all caracters are well rendered (even accents, cause I am french), except quotes, that are rendered as "`&#039;`".

Can anyone help me?

Here is an example of my code, in Symfony2

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
$response->headers->set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$name.'.csv"');
$response->setContent(utf8_decode($csv));
$response->setStatusCode(200);
```

Thank's a lot

Comment: `&#039;` is HTML encoding. Where are you doing HTML encoding? Also, keep in mind that Excel **can't** read UTF-8 data. If you're not using Excel .. lucky you ;)

Comment: Excel can read UTF-8. You can either use the Import Data tool, which will guess UTF-8 or you can add a UTF-8 BOM to your CSV. The latter method allows you to load a UTF-8 file straight into Excel.

Comment: If you're getting entity codes like `&#039;`, it implies that somewhere along the line you're doing a `htmlentities()` or something similar. Since the output isn't HTML, it isn't necessary to do that. I can't tell where you're doing that, as you haven't shown us the relevant code, but wherever it is, you probably need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers for you:

1. `utf8_decode` produces ISO-8859-1 content. Therefore your output is not UTF-8.
2. `&#039;` is the same in UTF-8, ASCII, Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1
3. I suspect `&#039;` is coming from your CSV source.
4. If you're building the source, ensure you use UTF-8 chars. Then you don't need to convert. If you're reading from disk, make sure you know the original character set. Don't convert character sets unless you know the original character set.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Symfony 4.4.
These are the 2 solutions that worked for me :

**1. First one:**

```php
// This import is used to inject a serializer object
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

$content = $this->serializer->serialize($csv, 'csv', [
    'csv_delimiter' => ';',
    'output_utf8_bom' => true,
]);

$response = new Response($content);
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $response->headers->makeDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, "$name.csv"
));
```

**2. Second one:**

`headers` => contains your headers.
`lines` => contains your lines.

```php
$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $response->headers->makeDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    "$name.csv"
));

$response->setCallback(function () use ($headers, $lines) {
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
    // Mandatory: Use bom + "Content-Type: application/force-download" => to allow to display special characters with excel
    fwrite($handle, $bom = chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF')));
    // headers
    fputcsv($handle, $headers, ';');
    // data
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        fputcsv($handle, $line, ';');
    }
    fclose($handle);
});
```